# Bug in Opencv's warping

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Even a slight change in the angle, as little as 0.001, results in significantly different outcomes.
Upon analyzing the ROI, it is evident that the area with a height of 592 is absent.
The warped image appears to have an erased effective area.
This phenomenon is observed within the angle range of 70 to 90 degrees.

Is there any possible solution or approach to address this issue?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

def plot_image(img, figsize_in_inches=(5, 5)):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize_in_inches)
    ax.imshow(cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.show()

img = cv2.imread('1.png')

image_height, image_width  = img.shape[:2]
focal_length = 800
print(focal_length)
image_center = (image_width / 2, image_height / 2)


K = np.array([[focal_length, 0, image_center[0]],
              [0, focal_length, image_center[1]],
              [0, 0, 1]], dtype=np.float32)

R = Rotation.from_euler('zxy',[0,   90, 0], degrees=True).as_matrix().astype(np.float32)
#R = Rotation.from_euler('zxy',[0,   90.001, 0], degrees=True).as_matrix().astype(np.float32)

warper = cv.PyRotationWarper("spherical", 1000)

_, warped_image = warper.warp(img,K, R, cv.INTER_LINEAR, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT)

warped_rois = warper.warpRoi((image_width, image_height), K, R)

print(warped_rois)
plot_image(warped_image)
```

You can easily understand what I want by refering the following images captured.

For 90.001 degree:
[image: For 90.001 degree]

For 90 degree:
[image: For 90 degree]

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do. Do not expect us to read your code and understand it. That takes too much time on our part.

Comment: Check the images....

For "90.001 degree" and "for 90 degree"

Comment: I do not understand what you want to do or to happen.  Do not expect us to understand your issue if you do not explain what you are trying to do!  Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I doubt it is a bug in OpenCV. I think it is a bug in your understanding of what happens when you do your warping.

Comment: With a very high focal length, tiny rotations of a camera have a high impact on the visible scene. Can you try to lower the focal length and repeat your experiment?

Comment: And please also post your R for both angles.

Comment: I agree that this seems weird. Do you get a similar large change if you add another 0.0001 to the angle? How about subtracting that amount from 90? Do you see the effect at other angles too? 90 is likely some break point, a special case maybe?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the limits of the warping formula are exceeded if you drive the x-parameter that far. It happens as soon as the upper left and upper right bow hit the screen's corners (format of window header is `f"{deg:.2f}: {warped_rois}`):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]